# Unordered list with list style type: none; & list-style-position: inside; takes extra space in Firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox

I like to have the bullets and numbers aligned vertically in a proper manner with the text contents in list elements throughout entire site. So I always put..

`ol, ul { list-style-position: inside; }`

But in case of `ul` sections where bullets are to be removed, I use..

`ul.nobullet { list-style-type: none; }`

This works perfectly in Chrome, Opera & Safari.

But in case of Firefox, simple `list-style-type: none;` doesn't seem to work properly. The bullets disappear as it should but there remains a gaps(space) right on the left of the li elements. I need to add additional `list-style-position: outside;` to the `ul.nobullet` to remove the gap.

My question is, why is this specifically happening in firefox? Is there something that I'm missing or doing wrong?

Here is a sample code. Note the gaps b/w the `li` items and the surrounding red border of `ul` in both Firefox and Chrome.

```css
* {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

ul {
    list-style-position: inside;
    border: 1px solid red;
}

.box {
    padding: 10px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}    

.nobullet {
    list-style-type: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
    <div><strong>Library Stats</strong></div>
        <ul class="nobullet">
            <li>line 1</li>
            <li>line 2</li>
            <li>line 3</li>
            <li>line 4</li>
            <li>line 5</li>
        </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: What version and what platform? I'm not seeing any difference between Firefox 35 and Chrome 40 on Windows 7.

Comment: I'm on Windows 8. Browsers - Chrome latest Screenshot [link](http://gyazo.com/f5e8fbf2deb6a2b4615077c931bf0d9d)

Firefox 29.0.1 Screenshot [link](http://gyazo.com/dadeabd48b5d183801ac3debc575f0a0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it!

I have been using Firefox 29.0.1. Which showed me this:
[image: Firefox 29.0.1]

Now I updated to Latest Firefox 35.0.1. And it's showing me this:[image]

If I can call this a fix of Firefox, then definitely it was a bug in earlier versions.

Answer (score 0):

It's not only Firefox. More correct way is to remove padding:

```css
ul { 
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Item 1</li>
  <li>Item 2</li>
  <li>Item 3</li>
  <li>Item 4</li>
</ul>
```

UPDATE:

Reading your code I found the point. You set padding 0 here:

```
* {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
```

It affects your list. Try no remove `padding: 0` and you'll see not `list-style-position` solves you problem.

Comment: The padding thing, it doesn't work. I already have a reset css but I've also tried setting `padding: 0;` to both `ul` and `li` element individually. The mysterious space comes into picture only after setting  `list-style-position: inside;`

Comment: Have you tested my sample on Firefox? It works fine! May be you have something else in your code that was missed in your explanation? What about to provide some jfiddle illustrating the problem?

Comment: Here is the fiddle: [link](http://jsfiddle.net/muwrajd6/1/) - check the gaps b/w the `li` items and the surrounding red border of `ul`.

Comment: I've load you jfiddle into Firefox, removed the 'list-style-position: inside;' and nothing changed. So, what's the trick and what's your question?
Please carefully read following article: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_list-style-position.asp

Comment: If I remove the `list-style-position: inside;` in Firefox, the space disappears. I've also added the screenshots as to how I see them in the comment of the original post. I don't meaningfully understand what you wrote in the update.